# JQuery Won't work?

Tags: jquery

First, let me get this straight. I am a complete newbie in JS & JQuery and I copied this code off from another site and can't get it to work!
I have no Idea how to fix it or how this works.
This code is supposed to enter some data into a textarea, but it will not do it. 
So, Here is the code;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
      $.fn.extend({
      insertAtCaret: function(myValue){
      var obj;
      if( typeof this[0].name !='undefined' ) obj = this[0];
      else obj = this;

      if ($.browser.msie) {
        obj.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
        obj.focus();
        }
      else if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.webkit) {
        var startPos = obj.selectionStart;
        var endPos = obj.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = obj.scrollTop;
        obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, startPos)+myValue+obj.value.substring(endPos,obj.value.length);
        obj.focus();
        obj.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        obj.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        obj.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      } else {
        obj.value += myValue;
        obj.focus();
       }
     }
    })

</script>
```

The textarea:

```
<br><textarea name="newPost" placeholder="Post Text" cols="100"  rows="10"/></textarea><br>
```

How Will I be able to configure this to work? I am really sorry for the dumb question.. I can't help it.  And I just gave up trying to get this working myself with no success.

Comment: "It will not do it" is not a valid problem statement.  Can you be more specific about the problem you are having?

Comment: You can use browser debugging tools (FireBug, Chrome tools, etc.) to step through the code and more precisely determine what is failing and where.

Comment: [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) has been removed with version 1.9

Comment: @David I dunno if a complete newbie to js knows about any debugging tools or how to use them

Comment: @Huangism: No time like the present for him to start trying then.  Once he knows they exist, the next step is to open them up and see what they do.

Comment: @David I agree, I just think OP would've no idea what to do or where to even start which is why I voted to close this question because I don't even think OP has the knowledge to understand any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the entire problem, but if a `<script>` element has a `src` attribute specified, the content of the script will be ignored. You need two script tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.fn.extend({
      ...
</script>
```